# Why the segmentation fault while trying to populate a gtk_list?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gtk2

I want to populate a gtk2 gtk_list and I try this block of code in a function:

```
GList (*List) = NULL;
GtkWidget (*ListBox) = gtk_list_new();
List = g_list_prepend(List, "List Item");
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(Vbox), ListBox);
gtk_list_prepend_items(GTK_LIST(ListBox), List);
```

I am sure that nothing is wrong with my function. I get a segmentation fault? Why? And what exactly can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are segfaulting because you are mixing **GList** and *deprecated* **GtkList** list functions.

The old [GtkList](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkList.html) is deprecated and not the same as [GList](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html). Notice:

```
GList (*List) = NULL;
...
List = g_list_prepend(List, "List Item");
/* now you switch to gtk_list_... and GtkList */
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(Vbox), ListBox);
gtk_list_prepend_items(GTK_LIST(ListBox), List);
```

Solution: just use `GList` and `g_list...` functions and avoid the deprecated `GtkList` and `gtk_list...` counterparts. `GList` and `g_list...` were designed to replace the earlier types and functions and will work seamlessly when compiled in your Gtk+2 application.

Comment: How exactly do I do that

Comment: Just use the `GList` and `g_list...` type and functions instead of `GtkList` and `gtk_list..`. Basically `GList` and `g_list..` are what the current `glib` supports. While you should be able to still use `GtkList` and the `gtk_list..` variants, don't. They will likely be removed completely from glib (if they haven't been already). The biggest issue is "You Can't Mix Them..."

Comment: What is "gtk_list..." what is the"..."

Comment: Sorry, that is just `gtk_list_(put_applicable_name_here)`. It's just the prefix. E.g. `gtk_list_prepend_items` is the deprecated version `g_list_prepend` is current. See [GList family of functions](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html) (they even have decent examples on the page -- rare)

Comment: I am trying to make the listbox that will display onscreen. The way I understand it, you use `gkt_list_...` to create the widget to display, and you use a `GList` with items added by `g_list_...` to make it display the items

Comment: I am saying, I am not using `GtkList`. The variable, `ListBox` is a `GtkWidget`

Comment: Yes, I see you are attempting to pack the `gtk_new_list()` into  In your code, either change `GList` to `GtkList` and `g_list_prepend` to `gtk_list_prepend_item` or vice versa. Also Note: [GtkListBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListBox.html) is not the same as `GtkList` or `GList` (both doubly-linked lists) and `GtkListBox` is the display item. You don't need the `GList` at all for the `GtkListBox`.

Comment: If you just want at text list [GtkComboBoxText](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html)

Comment: @16squared - if you are still having trouble with it, I wrote a short combo_box example for your here [combo_box_text Example](http://susepaste.org/69929220) (good for 1 month)